# Google maps API convert from V2 to V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I am jrying to convert the following 2 google m aps V2 API events to V3 but cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it, would it be possible for someone to give me some pointers on this?

```
    GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay, point){
    if (point != null) {
      window.status = "Click " + point.lat() + ", "+ point.lng();
    } 
          else if (overlay != null) 
        {
      window.status = "Overlay " + lastPoint.lat() + ", "+ lastPoint.lng();
    }
});
GEvent.addListener(map, "mousemove", function(point){
 lastPoint = point;
});
```

Comment: What is _exactly_ your problem?

Comment: I cannot find the equivelent for map, "click", function(overlay, point)

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  Tagging this question with `google`, `maps` and `api` does not mean you are talking about the Google Maps API for Javascript.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  console.log(event.latLng);
});
```

*"No overlay argument exists in v3 event listeners. If you register a click event on a v3 map the callback will only occur when the user clicks on the base map. You can register additional callbacks on clickable overlays if you need to react to those clicks. "*
- https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3#events

Answer (score 0):

if you need click through overlay and let overlay clickable, propagate click from overlay:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), mapOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    console.log(event.latLng);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(overlay, 'click', function(event) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'click', event);
});
```